# How can I combine two If Statements in PHP to block access to a URL?

Tags: php, joomla

I need to block access to all URLs that doesn't contain `&uuid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

the `x` is random and can contain number and text.
The final code needs to have both verifications in it: `if ($context->data->ticket->ohanah_event_id)` and the URL check.

The Code used at the Moment is:

```
<?php

/**
 * @package     Ohanah
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2012 - 2016 Beyounic SA. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU GPLv3 <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 * @link        http://www.beyounic.com
 */

class ComOhanahViewTicketHtml extends ComOhanahViewHtml
{
    protected function _fetchData(KViewContext $context)
    {
        parent::_fetchData($context);

        if ($context->data->ticket->ohanah_event_id) {
            $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
            $translator = $this->getObject('translator');

            $doc->setTitle($translator->translate('COM_OHANAH_TICKET') . ' - ' . $context->data->ticket->event->title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kaddath I am learning PHP at the moment, thats why I was unable to test something. I know that this could be accomplished with regex but I realy don't know how :(

Comment: @Kaddath From what I can understand the Documentation of the Framework used, this is used to get a View of the PHP.  But what the `$context` does, I have no idea :/ http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:RjEzZ2ovgHAJ:api.nooku.org/class-KViewContext.html+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de

Comment: if (isset($context->data->ticket->ohanah_event_id) &&$ strpos($url, '&uuid=') == false)

Is this what you needed??

Comment: @Abhinav yes, I think that this is something that could work but I get: syntax error, unexpected 'strpos' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: it is because i cant write it in code format in comment i putting it as a answer

Comment: Your question is Unclear about the characters that are expected at each `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be something like this.. if you give me more precisions of what the uuid format will be, i can update with a better regex. Some things like if the the example shows the accurate number of `x` separated by `-`, the regex would be `'/^[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}$/'`. (Note that theses regexes does not support accented characters)

```
class ComOhanahViewTicketHtml extends ComOhanahViewHtml
{
    protected function _fetchData(KViewContext $context)
    {
        parent::_fetchData($context);

        if(!isset($_GET['uuid']) || !preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9-]*$/', $_GET['uuid'])){
            exit('URL NOT ALLOWED!');
        }else{
            if ($context->data->ticket->ohanah_event_id) {
                $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
                $translator = $this->getObject('translator');

                $doc->setTitle($translator->translate('COM_OHANAH_TICKET') . ' - ' . $context->data->ticket->event->title);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if headers are not sent yet, you can add an accurate forbidden error with `header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');` (simple version, you can find better ones that accept HTTPS and all)

Comment: This looks better, but I get `syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    class ComOhanahViewTicketHtml extends ComOhanahViewHtml
    {
        protected function _fetchData(KViewContext $context)
        {
            parent::_fetchData($context);
            $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            if(isset($context->data->ticket->ohanah_event_id) && strpos($url, '&uuid=') == true) {
                //here $url is your url
                $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
                $translator = $this->getObject('translator');

                $doc->setTitle($translator->translate('COM_OHANAH_TICKET') . ' - ' . $context->data->ticket->event->title);
            }
        }
    }
```

I think this is what you thinking

Comment: Okay, I tried this and now I get `syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)` I use `$url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` is this correct?

Comment: small mistake in answer i am correcting it. always get confused with this editor. two if was there.

Comment: Okay, i dont get an error but it also doesnt block the URL if there is no uuid in it :/

Comment: what do you need?? do you need to block all urls that dosnt contain uuid?? then put true instead of false

Comment: Yes, I need to block all urls that doesnt contain "uuid" after the "/" eg. `website.com/datablabablieblahblub?view=ticket&uuid=` needs to be displayed and `website.com/datablabablieblahblub?view=ticket&` needs to be blocked.

Comment: it will work with my code i think.. try putting true instead false in if statement.  look my last updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162062/discussion-between-abhinav-and-yokogfx).